# Ruby on Rails: User not deleting from the postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activeadmin, record, destroy

I'm working on a ROR application which uses ActiveAdmin. I'm trying to delete a user using batch action. It is showing the message of success but in actual it is not deleting the user from database (postgres).

Here is the code of batch action -

```
batch_action :destroy, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete the user?", do |ids|
   Application::RecordsDestroy.perform_async Application::User, ids
   redirect_to user_path, :notice => "User is deleted"
   end
```

This is the code of Records Destroy file -

```
  class RecordsDestroy
    include Sidekiq::App

    def perform(res_model, ids)
      records = res_model.constantize.where(id: ids).destroy_all
      Rails.logger.info "Records for model #{res_model} have been premanently deleted"
    end
  end
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with code? Why it isn't working?

Any kind of help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Which "success" message are you referring to? "User is deleted" or "Records for model #{res_model} have been premanently deleted"? If you don't see "Records for xxx" then it's likely that the background job wasn't enqueued to Redis.

Comment: @Ali The success message that I received is "User is deleted".

Comment: Try running your background job in Rails console and see whether "Records for model xxx" is logged in the Sidekiq log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a classic mistake when using Sidekiq. See [best practices](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple) on job parameters.

You must not pass an AR model or complex object directly, as this will not be serialized correctly by Sidekiq. Instead, you must pass a primitive, such as a string:

```rb
Application::RecordsDestroy.perform_async 'Application::User', ids
```

Related tip on debugging Sidekiq: Add

```rb
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

to your application initialization (e.g. `development.rb`), which will make your jobs run synchronously in you main process.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
Application::RecordsDestroy.perform_async('Application::User', ids)
```

Since you're using constantize, I think your job expects string as parameter.

Also you can check your sidekiq logs for error